# I put a table after a carousel but it appear under it. Why?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, carousel, dreamweaver

I've put a carousel in my project and it works perfectly.(THANK GOD!!) I'm trying to put a table right after my carousel but when I go check in the live mode or the "google chrome view" it appears under my carousel. Can you help me fix that :)

Here's a part of my coding, the part missing is the pictures and the empty caption.

[image: Where my table is][image: You can see a tiny bit on the right side]

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Index</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">, 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="css/Cpnstruction_BS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="3">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><h3>514 415-6969</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="15%"><img src="Logo_BS.png" width="165" height="120" alt=""/></td>
      <td width="77%"><h2>Des travaux Biens Structurés</h2></td>
      <td width="8%"><div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img src="Menu.png" width="46" height="45" alt=""/></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a href="Construction_BS.html">Construction BS</a></br>
      <a href="Services.html">Services</a></br>
      <a href="Realisations.html">Réalisations</a></br>
      <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
</td> 
      </tr> </tbody></table><table width="100%" border="3">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><h3><marquee scrollamount="6"">Construction BS surveille de près l’information diffusée sur la COVID-19 et met à jour ses protocoles de prévention en conséquence. Pour en savoir davantage sur la COVID-19, consultez <a href="coronavirus.html">la trousse d’information générale fournie par le gouvernement du Québec</a>. </marquee></h3>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<secton id="one" class="container-fluid"> 
<!--BEGIN CAROUSEL-->

<div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">

<li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

<div class="item active"><img src="Berri.png" alt="placeholder" width="1528" height="850" class="center">
</div>

<div class="item"> <img src="bathroom-3346387_1920.jpg" width="1267" height="850" alt="placeholder">

<div class="carousel-caption">
</div>

</div>

<div class="item"><img src="Cuisine.png" width="1270" height="850" alt="placeholder">

<div class="carousel-caption">
  
</div>

</div>

</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>

<span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>

<span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></div>

</secton>
<!--latest jQuery-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<!--Bootstrap JS-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></div>
          
<table width="100%" border="3">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
          <td><p>514 415-6969 │ Info"constructionbs.com</br>
          R.B.Q.:5791-7574-01</p></td>
      <td><img src="ACQ.png" width="145" height="60" alt=""/><img src="AECQ.png" width="146" height="60" alt=""/> 
    <img src="Certifie.png" width="69" height="60" alt=""/></td>
      <td><h4>Construction BS&copy; 2020</h4></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: The preview in Dreamweaver is not reliable. What does it look like in a browser?

Comment: You can't see it because it's behind the carousel :S

Comment: I found a picture that was smaller on my slider

Comment: you should provide complete code of your html.. we have no idea how carousel structure looks like?

Comment: There are multiple problems. You marked in tag you're using Bootstrap 4, but actually you're using Bootstrap 3. I suggest you to re-write the site in Bootstrap 4, which the built-in carousel is easy to setup: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/

Comment: Raptor: I tried with getboostrap.com but even when i was in the browser, it didn't show as a carousel it was one after the other and I had numbers before the pictures. 

ash: I will change it for the full version :)

Comment: I kind of have a way but i've got my buttons on it so i can't access the link under... because it's in the carousel.... I would love it if it was independante... @Raptor can you help me?

Comment: You should take a look into examples in Bootstrap 4 Carousel (link above). Also, your HTML contains a lot of deprecated syntaxes and nested tables; your images are now mixing with the HTML files, which is undesirable. You should fix these issues first.